# Putting a view behind the status bar

Tags: ios, statusbar

I'm trying to create a statusBar Background. However it seem to place it wrong i've set a View in the top of the viewController and applied following contraints:

```
-16 trailing
-16 leading
top space 0
height 24
```

However this is the result

[image]

Why is there a white space at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the background for your status bar in the next very straightforward way :

```
// Set the status bar to red
var statusBarView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 22))
statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Put in the above code in your `viewDidLoad()` it should be work. I put the 1024 size for the `width` of the `UIView` but you can change it according your needs of the device you want.

I hope this help you.